# BizTalk 2010 Element repeating in output without data

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-mapper

I have a map going from a proprietary flat file to an X12 4010 204 file. There is an element in the 210 file called "piece", with attributes beneath it which are conditionally mapped and outputting as desired. The problem is the current output looks like this:

```
<DeclaredValueINS/>
<ShipperAttn/>
<PiecesDetail Pieces="0">
   <Piece/>
   <Piece/>
   <Piece/>
   <Piece/>
   <Piece width="45.5" length="9.25" description="Riverside Furniture Placid Cove 42 Inch Round/Ov" count="1" height="49" weight="90" SerialNumber="16753-16754-Kit"/>
   <Piece width="10.75" length="10.5" description="Riverside Furniture Placid Cove 42 Inch Round/Ov" count="2" height="23" weight="15" SerialNumber="16753-16754-Kit"/>
   <Piece width="21.25" length="11.75" description="Riverside Furniture Placid Cove X-Back Side Chai" count="2" height="41.37" weight="22" SerialNumber="16759"/>
   <Piece width="21.25" length="11.75" description="Riverside Furniture Placid Cove X-Back Side Chai" count="1" height="41.37" weight="22" SerialNumber="16759"/>
</PiecesDetail>
```

There is nothing mapped to the "Piece" element, nor a Loop above it (In fact, I have no idea how it is naturally looping through the data but am happy it is doing so). What I want is to suppress the  elements---other output (yes I have looked at and duplicated the logic from the other maps like this one) doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had it backwards--it was 204 to proprietary XML. I simply had to add the node to the conditions controlling the output of the desired lines below.